# Seven, Eight, Nine Redefined - A 'What Am I?' Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> Seven follows suit,
>
> Eight go in line,
>
> Combined, 9 leave the queue.
>
> Leaving i e,  once removed, rearranged casts light upon the answer.
>
> **What am I?**

HINT #1:

> I am a word.

HINT #2:

> Pay attention to punctuation.

HINT #3:

> Two of the three numbers in the riddle are not used like the other.

HINT #4:

> The sequence of numbers and their progression is NOT a nod towards the answer. For instance they do not reference something which is versioned (think computer software/OS) or of something that is incrementally changed (playing cards). This was intentionally misleading in the riddle to add to its complexity but I am revealing since all answers up to now have read in to it, distracting from the actual method to solve it.

Note: This riddle was previously closed for being "unclear" as to what it was asking. I have added a new tag, "word" (which is a hint in itself that I was trying to avoid originally), clarified the title and added the question "What am I?" at the end of the riddle. If this still is not clear enough please comment and suggest ways in which I can make it clearer. I am being cautious being overly specific as it is a short riddle and saying too much may reveal the answer.

Comment: the tag you might be looking for is "word" rather than "wordplay."

Comment: Ahh, thank you - editing now! I am going to include Hint #2 as well.

Comment: Do you mean i.e. or i e ?

Comment: You are getting somewhere, that is related to hint #2. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not believe this is the correct answer, but I believe this is the way to approach this riddle.

Seven follows suit,

> suitseven

Eight go in line,

> lieightne

Combined, 9 leave the queue.

> suitsevenlieightne - first 9 letters in the "queue" = lieightne

Leaving i e, once removed, rearranged casts light upon the answer.

> lieightne - ie = lightne --> lighten

What am I?

> The word "lighten"

Comment: You are correct! I was thinking "enlight"  but "lighten" uses the same letters and is basically a synonym so for that you get the green check!

Comment: What was the point of seven following suit though...?

Comment: @BaileyM That, and the fact that "eight" could go anywhere in "line" (since it would be anagrammed at the end anyway), and that there is no indication which 9 letters were to be removed, is why I didn't think this would be correct.

Comment: I'll chalk up the inelegant nature of the riddle to it being my first :) "Seven follows suit" was included to build the theme of lines/queues/following as well as the pattern of incrementation (7/8/9). These themes were meant to be distractions to add to the complexity mainly with a small intention of making the overall riddle feel more unique. I may have missed the mark it seems though.

Comment: Aw, I had tried this, but I guess I removed the letters wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

> Windows

*Seven follows suit,*

> Referring to Windows 7 which followed vista

Eight go in line,

> Windows 8 came afterwards

Combined, 9 leave the queue.

> Windows 10 feels like a mix between 7 and 8, for example, the start menu is a mixture of traditional Windows 7 combined with Windows 8 'tile' feel. However, Windows 9 never came to fruition

Leaving i e, once removed, rearranged casts light upon the answer.

> Windows 10 left internet explorer, is is now Edge. I think the 'rearranged casts light upon the answer' bit maybe refers to the UI

Comment: Cool idea - not the answer though - sorry! I will add another hint due to way in which you and @Zach_Gates perceived the riddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are:

> one of the 6 cards in a game of Patience (Solitaire)

---

7 follow suit

> 7 follows the number 6 in a column

8 go in line

> 8 is added to the column after 7

Combined, 9 leave the queue

> because 6, 7, and 8 are in the column, 9 can leave the deck (queue) and be added

Leaving i e, once removed, rearranged casts light upon the answer

> once you remove the numbers six through nine from the column, and add them to the bank of suits, you can rearrange your columns; making the solution to your game clearer

Comment: No sorry but a cool idea! I am editing and adding a hint now .

Comment: Aw, well it was a bit of a stretch. :P @IfTrue

Comment: @Zach_Gates I added another hint by the way!